# ANTLR4 idle org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig doesn’t output result

Tags: java, command-line-interface, antlr4

I compiled the:

```
grammar Hello; // Define a grammar called Hello
r : 'hello' ID ; // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ; // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines, \r (Windows)r
```

the command to generate the class files (notice I'm creating it with -package hellogrammer):

```
java  -jar antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar -package hellogrammer -o c:\Dev\my\java\ANTLR\test_project\core\src\main\java\hellogrammer c:\Dev\my\java\ANTLR\test_project\core\src\main\java\Hello.g4
```

and it creates the files just fine, then I compile the files and it looks like this:

```
c:\Dev\my\java\ANTLR\test_project\core\target\classes\hellogrammer>ls -1
HelloBaseListener.class
HelloLexer.class
HelloListener.class
'HelloParser$RContext.class'
HelloParser.class
```

Now when I try to execute the TestRig command I'm getting no response from the command line:

```
c:\Dev\my\java\ANTLR\test_project\core\target\classes>java -cp ".;C:/Dev/my/java/ANTLR/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig  hellogrammer.Hello -tree
```

It just stacks with no error or any response...

Comment: Try `cat in.txt | java -cp ".;C:/Dev/my/java/ANTLR/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig  hellogrammer.Hello r -tree`. You should give a start rule, and input. It's probably just reading stdin.

Comment: i dont have cat its windows

Comment: Try `type` instead of `cat`?

Answer (score 1):

The TestRig requires two separate parameters, first the grammar name and the the start rule name.  This TestRig then begins parsing input from the input stream, so, you can either type input (with a Ctrl-D for signal EOF), or you can redirect your input to stdin with `<`

Try:

```
c:\Dev\my\java\ANTLR\test_project\core\target\classes>java -cp ".;C:/Dev/my/java/ANTLR/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig hellogrammar.Hello r -tree < “your input file”
```

Comment: Requires "hellogrammer.Hello", not "Hello". Otherwise, the output is "Can't load Hello as lexer or parser".

Comment: Thanks.. I missed that he had specified a package.  Answer amended.